# How to correct Openvpn with elevated rights while being an ordinary user?

Tags: linux, vpn, openvpn, libraries

```
checking tap-windows.h presence... no
checking for tap-windows.h... no
checking whether TUNSETPERSIST is declared... yes
checking for setcon in -lselinux... yes
checking for pam_start in -lpam... no
checking for OPENSSL_CRYPTO... yes
checking for OPENSSL_SSL... yes
checking for EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_key_length... yes
checking for ENGINE_load_builtin_engines... yes
checking for ENGINE_register_all_complete... yes
checking for ENGINE_cleanup... yes
checking for ssl_init in -lpolarssl... no
checking for aes_crypt_cbc in -lpolarssl... no
checking for lzo1x_1_15_compress in -llzo2... no
checking for lzo1x_1_15_compress in -llzo... no
checking for PKCS11_HELPER... no
checking git checkout... yes
configure: error: libpam required but missing
[mirror@innov openvpn]$ ./configure --help | grep libpam
  --enable-pam-dlopen     dlopen libpam [default=no]
              C compiler flags for libpam
  LIBPAM_LIBS linker flags for libpam
[mirror@xxx openvpn]$ ./configure --prefix=/home/mirror/build/ins/ins_vpn --disable-lzo
```

**error: libpam required but missing**

I just have no privilege to install the package named libpam, so can I build libpam and install it in home directory, then build openvpn based on it?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, of course you can compile stuff as a regular user and point the configure script to it. Run `configure --help` and you'll probably see where it talks about setting environment variables like `LIBPAM_LIBS` and `LIBPAM_CFLAGS`. Set these manually to the location where the shared libraries (.so files) and headers (.h files) for a compiled libpam are.

I would advise that you set up a "local prefix" where openvpn and all of its dependencies can be aggregated. Think of this prefix as your own `/usr` directory.

Looks like from your setup that you're already setting --prefix to /home/mirror/build/ins/ins_vpn, so then /home/mirror/build/ins/ins_vpn/include would be the value to set for the environment variable `LIBPAM_CFLAGS` and /home/mirror/build/ins/ins_vpn/lib would be the value to set for the environment variable `LIBPAM_LIBS`. Of course, the environment variable names may vary depending on what `configure --help` says. So run it and read it.

You could also set `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` environment variable to `/home/mirror/build/ins/ins_vpn/lib/pkg-config` and the libpam `make install` step **should** push libpam.pc into that directory when installing (if you configure it with `--prefix=/home/mirror/build/ins/ins_vpn`). By setting PKG_CONFIG_PATH, you are instructing the `pkg-config` utility to look in that directory for `.pc` files, which contain data about the compilation and linking flags for programs. Many standard libraries use pkg-config and autoconfig, so you should be able to repeat these steps for any other packages.

Obtaining a proper version of libpam sources is probably just a matter of downloading the source rpm and unpacking the sources, or just figure out which version of libpam upstream your distro uses and grab that version (or a later version will probably work too).

Note that since you don't have root access on the box, you probably can't manipulate `tun` or `tap` devices (unless the sysadmin has given you privileges), so you probably won't be able to create a useful VPN tunnel without root anyway, even if you compile openvpn :)

Comment: seems libpam is in the kernel, so how to build it and install it as an ordinary user?  http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/libs/pam/

Answer (score 1):

> yum install gcc make rpm-build autoconf.noarch zlib-devel pam-devel
>   openssl-devel -y

This will resolve all the dependencies

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to install OpenVPN 2.3.0 via a `./configure` command as root and I was getting the same error about the libpam required but missing.  I installed the package **libpam0g-dev** and ran the `./configure` again successfully.

I know you said you don't have root, but if you can install that package, it will probably let you finish the `./configure` you're trying to do.